# Sistema de votación

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

estoy practicando con javascript y quiero hacer un sistema de votación. Cuando le doy a votar me muestra el voto en porcentaje, ahora cuando le doy otra ves me muestra la misma cantidad, osea cuando me tiene que dar un numero mayor 0,02%, no me suma el número 1 a 2.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".boton1").click(function(){
      var num = 1;
      for(var i = 0; i <= num; i++){
         var total = num / 100;
      }
      alert(total);
      num +1;

 }); 
});
```

Comment: tu variable num=1 es una variable local declarada en el cick, cada vez que llames a click reinicias esta variable.

Answer (score 0):

- Tu primer problema es que en el ciclo solo sumas, por lo que el resultado de salida siempre sería el mismo
- Si deseas que la suma se vaya incrementando tienes que aplicar:

Algunas de las sigueintes sintaxis:

```
variable = variable + algo
```

O bien así:

```
variable += algo
```

- Recomiendo que declares tus variables al inicio y por fuera del evento que estas tratando de vigilar, en este caso el `click`
- Ya que tu ejercicio en principio parece simple, la solución que te propongo es basada enteramente en JS

Código:

```html
    <button id="btn">Vota</button>
    <script>
        let boton  = document.getElementById("btn")
        let numero = 1
        let total  = 0
        boton.addEventListener("click", () => {
          for(let inicio = 0; inicio<=numero; inicio++)
            {
              total += numero / 100
            }
        console.log(total)
        numero + 1
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un porcentaje siempre se mide entre 0 y 100, siempre es menor a *%100*.

Para medir un porcentaje se usa esta fórmula:

> 100 * votos positivos / total de votos

Los botones serán los siguientes:

```
<button id="positivo">Positivo</button>
<button id="neutro">Nulo</button>
<button id="reiniciar">Reiniciar</button>
```

- El botón `#positivo` suma un voto positivo. Esto significa que en consecuencia de sumar el voto positivo, aumenta la cantidad de votos totales.
- El botón `#neutro` suma un voto neutro. Esto significa que aumenta la cantidad de votos totales, pero no aumenta la cantidad de votos positivos porque es neutro.
- El botón `#reiniciar`, reinicia la cantidad de votos totales y la cantidad de votos positivos al valor original, que era *cero (0)*.

Etiquetas *HTML* para resultados, en este caso usaré `h2`:

```
<h2 id="porcentaje"/>
<h2 id="total"/>
<h2 id="positivos"/>
```

- Porcentaje: Aplica la fórmula `100*positivos/total`
- Total y positivos: Simplemente accede al valor de tales variables.

En la parte de *JavaScript* declaro las variables para el total y los positivos:

```
var positivos = 0
var total = 0
```

Hago una función para calcular el total, que sea llamada desde el evento `click` de cada botón:

```
function calcular_total(){
  var porcentaje = 100*positivos/total

  $("#porcentaje").html( "%"+porcentaje )
  $("#total").html("Total: " + total )
  $("#positivos").html("Positivos: " + positivos )
}
```

Esta función, además de calcular el porcentaje, lo que hace es mostrarlos en las etiquetas `h1`, que tienen diferentes `id`, `#porcentaje`, `#total` y `#positivo`.

Lo último es asignar funciones a los eventos `click` del botón:

```
$("#positivo").click(function(){
  ++positivos
  ++total
  calcular_total()
})
$("#neutro").click(function(){
  ++total
  calcular_total()
})
$("#reiniciar").click(function(){
  positivos=0
  total=0
  calcular_total()
})
```

- En `#positivo` se aumenta los votos *positivos* y el *totales*.
- En `#neutro` se aumenta los votos totales.
- En `#reiniciar` se asigna a *cero (0)* los votos *positivos* y *totales*. Esta función el *porcentaje (%)* muestra *NaN* ya que no se puede dividir por cero, es decir, hay un total de cero votos.

En los tres botones, se llama a la función que calcula el porcentaje y los muestra.

Código completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var positivos = 0
  var total = 0

  function calcular_total(){
  
    var porcentaje = 100*positivos/total
  
    var tiempo = 100
  
    $("h2").fadeOut(tiempo).fadeIn(tiempo)

    setTimeout(function(){
      $("#porcentaje").html( "%"+porcentaje )
      $("#total").html("Total: " + total )
      $("#positivos").html("Positivos: " + positivos )
    },tiempo)
    
  }

  $("#positivo").click(function(){
    ++positivos
    ++total
    calcular_total()
  })
  $("#neutro").click(function(){
    ++total
    calcular_total()
  })
  $("#reiniciar").click(function(){
    positivos=0
    total=0
    calcular_total()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="positivo">Positivo</button>
<button id="neutro">Nulo</button>
<button id="reiniciar">Reiniciar</button>

<h2 id="porcentaje"/>
<h2 id="total"/>
<h2 id="positivos"/>
```